# Get Property Name from JSON

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I want to parse a JSON object with System.Text.Json like this:

```
[{
    "success": {
        "/a/b/c": false
    }
}]
```

I want to find out if the first property is named e.g. success or error with the following code:

```
using (var document = JsonDocument.Parse(test))
{
  var root = document.RootElement;
  var success = root.EnumerateArray().Current;
  Console.WriteLine(success);
}
```

but somehow I cant get to the success property and most importantly its name.

Comment: There's an example of enumerating through the properties of any object in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58273914/3744182) to [Converting newtonsoft code to System.Text.Json in .net core 3. what's equivalent of JObject.Parse and JsonProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58271901/3744182).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON is an array of objects, so to get the name of the first property in the first entry in the array you can combine [`EnumerateArray()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.enumeratearray?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_JsonElement_EnumerateArray) and [`EnumerateObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.enumerateobject?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_JsonElement_EnumerateObject) like so:

```
using var document = JsonDocument.Parse(test);

var names = document.RootElement
    .EnumerateArray()
    .SelectMany(o => o.EnumerateObject())
    .Select(p => p.Name);

var firstName = names.FirstOrDefault();
```

That being said, the [JSON standard](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) defines an object as an *unordered set of name/value pairs* so you might not want to hardcode your code to check just the first property.  The following code checks whether the first object has **any** property of the required name:

```
var propertyName = "success";

using var document = JsonDocument.Parse(test);

var hasProperty = document.RootElement
    .EnumerateArray()
    .Take(1) // Just the first object
    .Any(o => o.EnumerateObject().Any(p => p.Name == propertyName));
```

If you want to check whether any object in the array has the required property, remove the `.Take(1)`.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hQwhFh).

Comment: Thanks for posting man the transition has been a bit painful.

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe this helps**

you gotta move that enumerator, (you gotta move that color teehveeeeeyyy....)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string json = "[{\"success\": {\"/a/b/c\": false}}]";
        using (var document = JsonDocument.Parse(json))
        {
            var root = document.RootElement;
            var enumerator = root.EnumerateArray();
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"You are now at array element {enumerator.Current}");

                var elementContentEnumerator = enumerator.Current.EnumerateObject();
                while (elementContentEnumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"You are now at property {elementContentEnumerator.Current.Name}");
                }

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**Also: Things to consider when manually parsing through JSONS**

There are a lot of powerful JSON Frameworks available for C#. And there are lot of things available, to make the code more fluent. Especially LINQ, which means Language Integrated Query. Have a shot at it. 
Most of this make working with JSONS and C# really convenient, etc.

So normally (unless it is a very special thing you are up to) you can say that, whenever you are manually parsing through a JSON, and manually looping through enumerators, like in the code above, you are probably not leveraging the full power of C# and it's libraries.

Please accept as answer when it did help,

Greetings, Mike