# how to set the jsonproperty for property names to the dto while using automapper?

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net, automapper

In my API I'm using automapper for mapping to model, and it is finely mapping the entity to model, but I want to add PropertyNames to the model. I used **Json.net's** **JsonProperty** but this is not working as excepted.

the below is the DTO class

```
public class StudentModel
{
[JsonProperty("Admission Number")] public string StudentId { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("Date of Birth")] public string DOB { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("Name")] public string StudentName { get; set; }
}
```

the below is the entity class

```
public class StudentEntity
{
public string StudentId { get; set; }
public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
public string StudentName { get; set; }
}
```

the mapping like this `mappingProfile.CreateMap<StudentEntity, StudentModel>()`
and the mapper is: `_mapper.Map<StudentEntity, StudentModel>(entity)).ToList();`

but I'm not getting the JSON property in the response

**the output like this**

```
{
"studentId": "30112020",
"dOB": "01-01-2020 12:00 AM",
"studentName": "rom"
}
```

**but I want to get like this**

```
{
"Admission Number": "30112020",
"Date of Birth": "01-01-2020 12:00 AM",
"Name": "rom"
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using [tag:json.net]?  ASP.NET Core 3.0 and later use a different serializer, [tag:system.text.json].  See [Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0: Newtonsoft.Json (Json.NET) support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#newtonsoftjson-jsonnet-support) and [Where did IMvcBuilder AddJsonOptions go in .Net Core 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55666898/3744182).

Comment: [tag:system.text.json] uses a different attribute to control the serialized property name, [`JsonPropertyNameAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute).  See [Converting newtonsoft code to System.Text.Json in .net core 3. what's equivalent of JObject.Parse and JsonProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58273914/3744182).

Comment: If you are sure you are using Json.NET a [mcve] specifying your asp.net-core version and how you generated the output JSON would increase the chance we can help you.

Comment: @dbc Thanks for the response it worked, when gave the JsonPropertName instead of JsonProperty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it worked, after following dbc's comment

```
public class ResponseJson
{
    [JsonPropertyName("StudentId")]
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("dob")]
    public string DOB { get; set; }
    [JsonPropertyName("StudentName ")]
    public string StudentName { get; set; }
}
```

instead of

```
public class StudentModel
{
[JsonProperty("Admission Number")] public string StudentId { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("Date of Birth")] public string DOB { get; set; }
[JsonProperty("Name")] public string StudentName { get; set; }
}
```